# How to unpivot dynamically

Tags: oracle, dynamic, unpivot

I have a table enroll like this-

```
Students                Class1               Class2                   Class3
student1                 1                      0                       1
student2                 0                      1                       0
student3                 1                      1                       0
studnet4                 0                      1                       1
```

And I want I output like this-

```
Class1 has 3 Students

Class2 has 2 Students

Class3 has 3 Students
```

I have made a query for that like this-

```
select classname||' has '||count(num)||' students 'as no_of_students from
(
select * from enroll )
unpivot (
num for classname in (class1,class2,class3)
) 
where num=1
group by classname;
```

But if there are more class than every time I had change in my in clause. I don't know pl/sql also. So if anyone can help?

Comment: Do not use the `count()` as an aggregate funtion, but use the `sum()` as an aggregate function. `select  classname||' has '||sum(num)||' students 'as no_of_students from group by classname`

Comment: there is no need for that count will also give the desired result as it will count rowid whre num=1. Beside that I want how to do dynmically?

Comment: can you provide a data - structure of the table `enrol`

Comment: its simple I have a column name student of varchar2 and class1,class2,class3,...classn of number datatype

Comment: Sorry for my delay ... In the end - I guess - there is a maximum number of classes. So "n" is maximized. If a student is not present in any class he/she will be administered as "0" in all classes. If you implement "n" classes in the `in` statement you can retrieve all situations. A dynamic solution is not necessary ... I guess.

Comment: How can you write a query for that?

Comment: I have tried using any but it won't take can you please give an example or something?

Comment: since the data structure is a fixed situation you will have to deal with that ... so an `in` clause like `num for classname in (class1, class2, class3, class4, class5, class 6, class 7, class 8, class 9, class10) etc etc` could be the answer. Otherwise you will have to re-desing your table structure and apply a one-to-many relationship between Class, DateTime Entity and Student.

Comment: that is the thing that I have to add columns name and I cant do it every time. I have tried by using pl/sql but I am not able to make it. Anyway thanks for your concern if you know pl/sql please help me.

Comment: perhaps the code in the answer can support you in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- it is an old-school solution, but it worked for me
-- step 1
create or replace procedure test_students
as

cursor c_cols
is
select column_name
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'ENROLL'
and column_name != 'STUDENTS';

l_number_of_students number;
l_my_col user_tab_columns.column_name%type;
l_statement varchar2(30000);

begin



 for r_cols in c_cols loop

 l_my_col := r_cols.column_name; 

 l_statement :=
 ' select sum('||l_my_col||')
   from enroll ';

 execute immediate l_statement into  l_number_of_students;

 dbms_output.put_line ('Number of students: '||l_number_of_students ||'in Class :'||l_my_col);

 end loop;




end; 

-- step 2
begin
test_students;
end;
/
```

Comment: I don't know what kind of problem is this but when I tried to execute test_students than it is showing 'anonymous block completed'
Earlier it was running but now what happened?

Comment: when you execute the step 2 statement you will have to `enable dbms_output`. In SQL+ the command is something like `> set serveroutput on size 1000000`. In toad you will have to switch the red button to green (this will enabale output int toad).

Comment: can you explain me the meaning of this line-
<for r_cols in c_cols loop

 l_my_col := r_cols.column_name;>

Comment: `for r_cols in c_cols loop` is the opening of the loop that refers to `cursor c_cols ` the `r_cols` is a record pointer that retrieves all columns in the cursor; in this example we only need `colum_name` (it is the only one provided in the query). ` l_my_col ` is a local variable that holds the value of `r_cols.column_name` just for one loop-through; in the next loop-throug you l_my_col will be overwriten with the next value from c_cols. It is rather simple pl/sql; an old-school solution; but this is how you start learning it